# Verilog Input Text Parsing using Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, text, extract, verilog

so I'm trying to parse some verilog files using python. I need to find inputs, outputs, etc. However, in some files, some inputs and outputs have multiple bitwidths, like so:

```
input read_enable,
input [WIDTH-1 : 0] write_data,
```

I'm using regular expressions to go through the text file one line at a time, so right now if the line contains the word input I run:

```
input_mod = re.search(r'(.*?)input\s(.*?)(\s?)(.*?),', line)
inputs.append(input_mod.group(4))
```

Where inputs is a list I declared earlier. I need to extract the input's name.
I'm rather new to python and regex's so I'm not sure if this will work, is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Note: I know doxygen exists, but my boss wants a native function in their python class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*?\binput\b.*? (\S+),
```

You can use this.`inputs.append(input_mod.group(1))`This will take care of everything in between `input` and the last non space string before `,`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/4#python

Comment: So from my understanding, the \b's takes care of the spaces, the .*? handles anything in between input and the name, and then the \S+ represents the actual name of the input?

Comment: @JustinWang `\b` defines word boundary.So `input` will match and `badinput` will not match neither will `inputs` match.rest all is correct

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I realized that the .*?'s would handle the spaces. Thanks so much!